# server method to unsubscribe clients

Tags: wamp, wampserver, wamp-protocol

Is there a method, which can be used by a server to destroy a client?

currently, only the client can unsubscribe/unregister from the WAMP server by itself. however, if the client crashes, the `subscribe id` stays occupied by a dead client. hence, we need to change the `subscribe id` manually and restart the client, which is not feasible in a productive environment.

Comment: Not at all sure what you are asking. Are you talking about SESSIONS's or some database activity? If you want an answer you are going to have to explain your situation more clearly.

Comment: I want to register a procedure, but get this exception:  `ApplicationError(wamp.error.procedure_already_exists`. This happens because the server crashed and therefore did not destroy the previous procedure. Hence, I'd like to know, if there is a way to delete these loose/dead procedures.

Comment: The problem with dead registrations is that there is no way for the router to distinguish an unclean disconnect of a WebSocket connection from an inactive/incredibly slow connection. To solve this, Crossbar.io allows you to activate WebSocket pings, so that dead connections are recognized within a configurable timeframe - see http://crossbar.io/docs/WebSocket-Options/